# How to enable wpf controls through data binding on a selected item from a combo box

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am looking for a way where a control can be enable when an item from a combo box is selected. Is there a simple way through data binding when a user selects an item from a combo box that it then enables another control to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You want to bind to IsEnabled in the target control which you want to dynamically enable or disable, and use a [Value Converter](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to convert a matching string or item from the ComboBox to a true value for being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVVM, you can bind the `SelectedItem` of the combobox to a property in your viewmodel.

Say this is your combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding widgetlist}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedwidget, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
```

And this is your control:

```
<DockPanel IsEnabled="{Binding controlenabled}">
    ...
</DockPanel>
```

Then in `selectedwidget`'s setter, you can change the `controlenabled` property to False or True. Don't forget to notify that the `controlenabled` property changed (or if you want, make `controlenabled` a DependencyProperty.)

In summary, you've got 3 properties to bind to:

- `widgetlist`, an ObservableCollection or some other collection that is the source for your combobox
- `selectedwidget`, an item of that collection type that changes to whatever the combobox currently has selected
- `controlenabled`, a `bool` that the other controls look at to decide if they are enabled/disabled.

Like many examples in MVVM, this way may require slightly more thought and code on the outset, but will be far more maintainable and scalable later. For example, say you want some more controls to also enable/disable themselves based on the same scenario. Piece of cake: add `IsEnabled="{Binding controlenabled}">` to them.